# What is the best way to model this hex gradient?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap, solidify-modifier

I'm a newbie and I am trying to model a hex gradient on a curved surface.  I created the gradient I wanted in Illustrator, brought in as an SVG, converted to mesh, and had a lot of finicky work to try to get quad construction.  Then I shrinkwrapped to my curved surface and now I'm trying to
solidify, but I'm having trouble.

Is there a more automated way to do this.  I know there is a 'honeycomb' features under 'extras' but I can't do a gradient of hex sizes.

[image]

Comment: What you've described sounds like the best method to get a size-gradient of hexagonal holes in Blender -- I don't think it's needed often enough for anyone to try to automate it.  That having been said, what you've described should solidify.  What trouble are you having?  Have you applied the shrinkwrap modifier?  Have you checked for duplicate vertices and flipped normals?  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: You can create this hexagon grid with *Geometry Nodes* and an *Array* and a *Boolean* modifier. Here is a try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDFBh.jpg. (I'll post an answer later.)

Comment: Thank you both for the answers.  My original issue was that I did not ensure that I merged everything before shrinkwrapping.  I actually did end up using Arrays in the end.  One thing I've noticed...my shrinkwrap is not smooth, even though I shrinkwrapped to a smooth curve.  Any ideas where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: I tried to shade smooth and Auto smooth, after shrinkwrapping and solidify modifiers and it seemed to do a good job.  Is this the best way to remove the bumps created by the hex pattern?